# changing data type in pandas dataframe changes filtering result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I am observing the following behaviour that I dont understand when filtering a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
mydict={'dep':[0,0,0,0],'nr':[1,1,2,2],'ft':[1,2,3,4],'car':['corsa','astra','clio','megane']}
carsdf = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
condition1 = carsdf['nr'] == 1
condition2 = carsdf['ft'] == 1
carsdf.loc[condition1 & condition2,['dep']]['dep'].tolist()
```

Result [0]

now I do the same again but after changing the type to str

```
carsdf = carsdf.astype('str')
condition1 = carsdf['nr'] == 1
condition2 = carsdf['ft'] == 1
carsdf.loc[condition1 & condition2,['dep']]['dep'].tolist()
```

Result  []

I would expect ['0']

No element inside. Why does the 0 go away when changing the type to str?

how can I assure that no data is lost?

NOTE: If you are wondering why I want '0' because the data received might also be in the form '2,3,4' which i the want to transform into a list of values. In case of 0 I need ['0']

here the screenshot

thanks

[image]

Comment: `condition1 = carsdf['nr'] == str(1)`
`condition2 = carsdf['ft'] == str(1)` Can you try this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are looking for comparison on an integer (`== 1`). If we try `== '1'` we get the expected result.

Sidenote, you can rewrite your last line more "pandas" way, see below

```
carsdf = carsdf.astype('str')
condition1 = carsdf['nr'] == '1'
condition2 = carsdf['ft'] == '1'
carsdf.loc[condition1 & condition2,'dep'].tolist()
```

**Output**

```
['0']
```